# OpenJDK Java 17 docker image

Tags: java, docker, java-17

We are upgrading our microservices in docker to use Java 17 and previously we used the base image openjdk:11-jre-slim. What is the corresponding image for Java 17?

There doesn't seem to be a openjdk:17-jre-slim? In fact there dont seem to be any recent jre images - just jdks. The 11-jre-slim image seems to be arount 75MB - is there a suitable similarly sized Java 17 image?

We have also used alpine images in the past too.

Comment: See this github issue: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/468 Upstream no longer provides a JRE, so no official JRE images will be produced. There is a similar discussion about [Adoptium (formerly AdoptOpenJDK) no longer releasing JREs](https://github.com/adoptium/temurin-build/issues/2683). For better or worse, official JREs are going the way of the Dodo.

Comment: That being said, it seems the jdk now comes with tools to produce custom JREs, so it should be possible to create one on your own: https://www.baeldung.com/jlink  and here an example from Eclipse Tamurin for a openjdk 11 JRE: https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin  https://blog.adoptium.net/2021/08/using-jlink-in-dockerfiles/

Comment: @kutschkem: yes, custom jlink-built base images are the alternative, but I wouldn't call those "JREs", because that's not exactly what they are and calling them that can lead to assumptions that aren't right and to confusion.

Comment: You can use [Alpine JDK 17](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/17-alpine/images/sha256-a996cdcc040704ec6badaf5fecf1e144c096e00231a29188596c784bcf858d05?context=explore) `FROM openjdk:17-alpine`

Comment: See also [How to create an Alpine-based JRE-only Docker image of Amazon Corretto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77343684/685806)

Answer (score 68):

Oracle image is freely available from Java-17 `openjdk:17-oracle`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
```

`openjdk:17-jdk-slim` also creates lightweight image

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
```

Comment: 17-oracle is the same tag for 17.0.1-jdk-oraclelinux8, jdk-oraclelinux8, 17.0.1-jdk-oracle, 17-jdk-oracle, 17-oracle, jdk-oracle, etc. Basically it is the same JDK image, not JRE. https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/openjdk/README.md#simple-tags

Comment: Doesn't this have licensing concerns? Most people want to avoid Oracle these day I would think

Comment: @Novaterata from Java 17 onwards, you can use it freely even for commercial purposes

Comment: @DeekshithAnand 

Comment: as @DeekshithAnand perfectly mentioned from Java 17 onwards, oracle image can be used freely.
If you are looking for a different image then - "openjdk:17-jdk-slim" also works fine to create a lightweight image

Comment: 2023 UPDATE: this answer is now outdated since the openjdk image has been deprecated. See [Paul Verest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75997220/15744300) for alternatives.

Answer (score 32):

(As of 2023) Do not use any `openjdk:17-` images, because
what you may get are old early jdk 17 builds
with security issues !
On https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk there is clear

> DEPRECATION NOTICE

openJDK 17 is not build anymore!
(and not maintained in https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk)

---

While it was simpler before to use whatever linux flavour,
now you need to make choice as different [openJDK builds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK#OpenJDK_builds) docker images
will use different linux flavours.

E.g. amazoncorreto - Amazon Linux,
Oracle JDK - Oracle Linux etc

---

Different sources may recommend differently

E.g. on https://docs.docker.com/language/java/build-images/ uses `eclipse-temurin`

> FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking for the tiniest Docker images with Alpine Linux and OpenJDK, have a look at Liberica JDK containers at DockerHub https://hub.docker.com/r/bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine
The images have Alpine and Liberica Lite, which is optimized in size to be used on microservices. It is also recommended by the Spring team https://spring.io/quickstart

Answer (score 9):

You can try this (`eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine`) which is around 50MB of compressed size
https://hub.docker.com/layers/eclipse-temurin/library/eclipse-temurin/17-jre-alpine/images/sha256-839f3208bfc22f17bf57391d5c91d51c627d032d6900a0475228b94e48a8f9b3?context=explore

I couldn't sill find an OpenJDK jre image

Answer (score 8):

Adding to @PaulVerest's excellent answer, for the benefit of other newbies like me, I am posting here the `Dockerfile` that works for me (as of May 2023, built and run from a `Windows 10` PC):

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17.0.7-alpine

# Add app user
ARG APPLICATION_USER=appuser
RUN adduser --no-create-home -u 1000 -D $APPLICATION_USER

# Configure working directory
RUN mkdir /app && \
    chown -R $APPLICATION_USER /app

USER 1000

COPY --chown=1000:1000 ./myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar" ]
```

If you built your container using:

```
docker build -t docker_myapp .
```

Then, run it from the command line using:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 docker_myapp
```

Note: You can't stop it from the same command line using `Ctrl+C`. To stop it, you need to open another command line and do:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                    NAMES
16dad8047672   docker_myapp   "java -jar /app/app.…"   7 hours ago   Up 7 hours   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   sharp_rode
```

Then:

```
docker stop 16dad8047672
```

Comment: `USER 1000` what does this aim for?

Comment: I salute thee sir.

Answer (score 4):

An update on this - looking again at the Eclipse Adoptium issue mentioned above (https://github.com/adoptium/temurin-build/issues/2683) the more recent comments indicate they have now started producing JRE images.

We have switched to using `eclipse-temurin:17-jre-focal`. There is also a (slightly larger) `17-jre-centos7` and a smaller `17-jre-alpine`, but we now need some libraries that aren't in alpine.

Answer (score 2):

In your Dockerfile [link](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/17-alpine/images/sha256-a996cdcc040704ec6badaf5fecf1e144c096e00231a29188596c784bcf858d05?context=explore):

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
```